# Pass View to method in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I ran into such a problem today that I cannot pass the View to the method.

I doing all this in order to get rid of the numerous dubbing code.

For example, I will show how I see it and if there is such the ability to pass to the method, then how to implement it the ability to pass to the method

[error when passing to the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALTr6.png)

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it gets you anywhere.

```
public class Test
{
    private SelectFrom<Account>.View testView;

   

    public void Test()
    {
        Method1(testView.View);
        Method2(testView);
    }

    public void Method1(PXView test)
    {

        
    }

    private void Method2(FbqlSelect<SelectFromBase<Account,TypeArrayOf<IFbqlJoin>.Empty>, Account>.View view)
    {
        var current = view.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I tried so, really I get a view but then I don't have "view_something.Current". How can i get Current?

Comment: In this method1() I have a "test.Cache", but I don't have "test.Current", if I access "textView" directly then Current is –

Comment: I added an alternate method to try. That seems to get into the Current member. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: No Problem glad you got what you need.

Comment: Could you tell me please, since this design works only with View without conditions "private SelectFrom<Account>.View testView;". tell me how to implement for View with the condition "public SelectFrom<NSIAsset>.Where<NSIAsset.nonStockItemID.IsEqual<InventoryItem.inventoryID.FromCurrent>.And<NSIAsset.tagInfo.IsEqual<NonStockTags.Ast>>>.View Asset;"